# Want to delete a row from a table using php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to delete a row  from a table using php pdo.I am using the following code,

```
 $dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=as1';
         $user = 'root';
         $password = '';
    try {
      // Connect and create the PDO object
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo 'Database connection failed - ';
     echo $e->getMessage();
     exit;
     }
    $sql1="DELETE FROM photo WHERE id=?";
        $q1=array($result);
                                try {
        $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
        $stmt1->execute($q1);
        $stmt1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

     $result1= $stmt1->fetchColumn();

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
```

But my datas in a table are not deleting ...It shows failed to run query..

Comment: You put your SQL into `$sql1`, and then prepare `$sql`

Comment: Since you have `$result1= $stmt1->fetchColumn();` you should be using `$q1=array($result1);`

Comment: What is the error message in the `die` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a value for `?`

```
$stmt1->execute($q);   // Where is $q defined?
```

Should be something like

```
 $q=array(1);
 $stmt1->execute($q);
```

Comment: Maybe the OP should be using `$stmt1->execute($q1);` as from `$q1=array($result);`

Comment: It says failed to run query

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky You're saying the OP should be using `$stmt1->execute($q1);` is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is, as long as $q1 contains that value for id

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky OP is obviously not being consistent with variables. There isn't much else to do here.